# Vue - Laravel not recognizing registered components

Tags: vuejs2

I am learning Laravel and Vue and i am trying to use Vue Select but haven't figure out how to make it work.

For reference [vue-select](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/#install) [vue-select github site](https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select)

I get a javascript error on the console that says :  "Unknown custom element: `<v-select>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

I have on my main.js the following code for the v-select component

```
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
```

And I am just going with the basic here, trying to figure out on how to display the select control

```
<v-select :options="[{label: 'foo', value: 'Foo'}]"></v-select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how you are importing `vSelect` in main.js file

Comment: just using this Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect); import returns error.

Comment: I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import with every import i make on my main.js